# Unity: Send Key to Background Window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a customizable on-screen keyboard with Unity, but am having trouble figuring out how to get the keyboard to send the keys to whatever window is behind it.

I have tried using a slightly edited version of [Louisbob's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805345/send-combination-of-keystrokes-to-background-window) code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

[SerializeField]
class SendMessages
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public static void sendKeystroke()
    {
        const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

        IntPtr hWnd;
        string processName = "Notepad";
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process P in processList)
        {
            if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
            {
                IntPtr edit = P.MainWindowHandle;
                PostMessage(edit, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)(Keys.B), IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class B_Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            SendMessages.sendKeystroke();
        }
    }

}
```

This code does not return any errors but when I run/build the project and click, no 'B' appears in Notepad.  Am I doing something wrong or does the PostMessage function not work with Unity?  If it does not work, what else can I do to get this program to work?

**Update**

I figured out that getting the handle on the window is one or the only problem.  I did

```
Process[] n = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
        foreach (Process p in n)
        {
            hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(hWnd);
        }
```

on multiple programs, that were running, and it returned 0 for both mainwindowhandles.  I am not sure what is causing this since the applications are running and not hidden, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Unity is not meant for "always on top" style applications where it has to pass input around, be transparent, etc.

Comment: Make sure the message is sent

Comment: did you try to debug step by step? Does `processList` have the entry(entries) you expect or is it maybe empty? Is `P.ProcessName.Equals(processName)` ever true? Maybe a `P.ProcessName.Contains(processName)` would be enough? Is `edit` set to a correct vaue?

Comment: @derHugo I posted an update. Thanks for the advice.  I just thought it must be the postmessage fcn. causing the issue.